# How to alias an option?

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a bash script where I want to alias some commands. I want to alias `rm` to, let's say `ls`:

```
alias rm="ls"
```

But then I also want to add custom `options` to my aliased rm command. I want to add `-u`. I can't do (for example):

```
alias rm -u="ls dir1"
```

The code above throws an error. My question is, how do I alias options to commands? So how do I make custom options? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alias` can't accept parameter. Create your custom function instead.

Comment: This cannot be done with an `alias`.  You will need to write a function.

Comment: This question might make more sense if the requested alias made sense as well. Why would you completely alter the meaning of the command `rm` in this way?

Comment: It's one thing to use an alias to add certain options as a default (`alias rm='rm -i'` is often used as a--somewhat controversial--safeguard against accidentally removing files), but making `rm -u` do something entirely different from from its original behavior seems to serve little purpose beyond obfuscating your use of the command line.

Comment: @chepner it's just my school assignment :)

Comment: @Ninini : Can you add an explanation, how you plan your alias to be invoked, and what effect it should have?

Comment: Basiclly what I need to do is, I need to make an alias for "rm" to change it's functionality. Then I need to add custom options to "rm" such as "-u". In reality, I don't have to do anything with "ls", what I need to do is a bit more complex, but I used "ls" as an easy way to explain what I need.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019685/how-to-alias-an-option#comment120222749_68019685); altering the function of `rm` could result in unexpected behaviour; ***use with caution***

---

The [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) states: <sup>[1](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/how-to-use-spaces-in-a-bash-alias-name)</sup>

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

---

A bash function that will override `rm -u` could look like this:

```sh
rm() {
    if [[ "$@" == "-u" ]]; then
        ls dir1
    else
        ls
    fi
}
```

Where

- `rm -u` will run `ls dir1`
- Every other `rm *` will run `ls`

Comment: That gets an error when called with more than one parameter.

Comment: Mm could you please show the command? Unable to reproduce on my bash/

Comment: I was wrong! But ShellCheck recommends using `$*` over `$@`, because that's what happens implicitly anyway within `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I NEED to make rm an alias and then add -u in another way (so for example with this function). How could I combine alias rm="ls" with your function to add -u to the my custom rm?

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to do this method, but: anyway, you can do:

```
$ alias somerm="ls "
$ alias -- -u=dir1
$ somerm -u
ls: cannot access 'dir1': No such file or directory
```

The trailing space in an alias causes alias to be applied on the next word on the command line, in this case on `-u`, which alias substitutes for `dir1`.

> How do I make custom options?

Options:

- write your own utility from scratch with the added option
- patch the utility with your own option and distribute it (preferably with a different name and configure your shell to use your own utility instead of standard one)
- create a wrapper around the utility to "catch" the new options and apply custom semantics to the utility (ie. a function, as in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

`rm` as a function, using (IMO) proper option parsing:

```sh
rm () {
    local OPTIND OPTARG
    local real_command="ls"
    local command_args=()
    while getopts :u opt; do
        case $opt in
            u) command_args+=( "dir1" ) ;;
            ?) echo "unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2
               return 1 
               ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))

    "$real_command" "${command_args[@]}" "$@"
}
```

Just a *smidge* more verbose than an alias, but that's the way bash is.